# Does pigpiod feature a verbose / debug mode?

Tags: pigpio

As I'm currently trying to debug an issue with my SPI link, which is addressed through pigpio, I'd like to make pigpiod write warnings and debug messages (if such occur) to stderr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors are reported to `/dev/pigerr` on the Pi running the daemon.

So `cat /dev/pigerr` may provide useful information.

You can enable tracing of the API by using the [pigs csi](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#CSI) command.

Numbers 1 to 7 should uncover more tracing.

Try something like `pigs csi 5` or `pigs csi 6`.

The results will be sent to `/dev/pigerr`.

Comment: OK, thank you! `pigs csi 5` was apparently the solution. I now get quite a lot of debug messages.

Comment: Keep in mind that `/dev/pigerr` is a FIFO. Use `cat` as recommended, not `tail -f`, which will not show you anything.